# Sati • Yonisomanasikara

Tags: theravada, terminology, sati

Dearest friends, seeking to clarify my fragmentary understanding of these matters, I would very much appreciate your comments on the distinction between **Sati** *Mindfulness* and **Yonisomanasikara** *Attention by way of the Matrix*.

Warmhearted, grateful thanks for you taking the time to offer some help.

Answer (score 2):

Samma Sati is a factor of Noble Eightfold Path. Yonisomanasikara is a factor of Sotapanna. Perhaps Yonisomanasikara is the fruit of following the path. (practicing Satipathana)

Further reading:
Association with people of integrity is a factor for stream-entry.
Listening to the true Dhamma is a factor for stream-entry.
Appropriate attention is a factor for stream-entry.
Practice in accordance with the Dhamma is a factor for stream-entry.
— SN 55.5

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/study/into_the_stream.html

https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=31179&hilit=

Comment: For a change we both agree!! -)

Comment: I respect your contribution and appreciate it but this came to my senses when I listened to Ven. Vijithananda.

Answer (score 1):

Sati is a factor of concentration. Sati means remembering.

Yonisomanasikara is a factor of wisdom. It means thoroughly examining.

For example, you read or hear Dhamma Teachings. The teachings say you should thoroughly examine & think about the teachings after hearing the teachings. This thoroughly examining & thinking about the teachings is yonisomanasikara.

Then when the teachings are understood, you continuously remember to keep the teachings in mind so you can continuously practise the teachings. This continuously remembering to keep the teachings in mind & to not be forgetful of the teachings is sati (mindfulness).

> Thus associating with good persons, becoming full, fills up hearing
>   the good Dhamma. Hearing the good Dhamma, becoming full, fills up
>   faith. Faith, becoming full, fills up **careful attention** (**yoniso
>   manasikārā**). Careful attention, becoming full, fills up mindfulness
>   and clear comprehension. **Mindfulness** (**sati**) and clear comprehension, becoming
>   full, fill up restraint of the sense faculties. Restraint of the sense
>   faculties, becoming full, fills up the three kinds of good conduct.
>   The three kinds of good conduct, becoming full, fill up the four
>   establishments of mindfulness. The four establishments of mindfulness,
>   becoming full, fill up the seven factors of enlightenment. The seven
>   factors of enlightenment, becoming full, fill up true knowledge and
>   liberation. Thus there is nutriment for true knowledge and liberation,
>   and in this way they become full.
>
> AN 10.61

Answer (score 0):

I caution people not to oversimplify and separate ideas into definite categories. Many special terms in Dhamma are nuanced and straddle several categories simultaneously.

IMO the best bet is find the suttas which best exemplify the term and try to understand it in that context.

Two of the best, IMO, are SN 46.2 and AN 7.63.

http://lucid24.org/sn/sn46/sn46-002/index.html
watch how yoniso and a-yoniso mana sikara are used in that sutta.

now think about the relationship from that, and what the gatekeeper (sati) does in this sutta:
http://lucid24.org/an/an07/an07-0067/index.html

Comment: I edited this answer. BSE is not a debating site. Please do not include my answer within your answer. Thank you

Comment: @frankk Am I right in guessing that you're the author of lucid24.org? If so it would be better to mention that in your answer here, when you reference that site -- for example you could answer something like, "See my translation and synopsis at http://lucid24.org/sn/sn46/sn46-002/index.html and watch how yoniso and a-yoniso mana sikara are used in that sutta." -- and/or disclose your affiliation in your user profile. I ask because [this Help topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) says, "you must disclose your affiliation in your answers" (if there is an affiliation).

Comment: chrisW, yes, i've updated my profile to include that disclaimer.

Comment: Dhammadhatu, please don't edit my answers in a self serving way and abuse your editor privileges. Please restore my answer to its original form. This is not a debate. You posted some incomplete/misleading/wrong information, I pointed it out. You had your say, I had my say, and it's not a debate unless you make it so. I consciouslessly had not downvoted your answer before, but now that you're making an issue of it I downvoted it.

Comment: (Dhammadhatu's account is temporarily suspended.)

Comment: I think Dhammadhatu's edit was alright. One of the ways to ensure that this remains a Q&A (question and answer) site, instead of a "forum", is for each answer to answer the OP's question independently, instead of addressing other answers -- this helps to avoid debate and cross-talk between the authors of different answers. I think your answer still makes perfect sense even with the edit, i.e. it's on-topic and directly answers what the OP is asking.

Comment: If you think that an answer (like DD's) is wrong then it might be allowable to post a comment under the answer -- but it's usually better to (instead of commenting on the other answer) post another better answer of your own instead.